# perl6 How do lists returned by (pattern)* and m:global/(pattern)/ differ?

Tags: list, match, global, raku

Perl6 returns a list when capturing with (pattern)* or (pattern)+ and I would imaging that something similar will happen when :g adverb is used. However, the lists returned by using these 2 methods are not the same. The documents did not give more details. Is there any other source to find more info?

Here is an example:

```
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my $a = "bananananananana";
bananananananana
> my $m = ($a ~~ m/ (an)+ /)
｢ananananananan｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
> say $m[0]
[｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣]
> say $m[0][0]
｢an｣
> say $m[0][2]
｢an｣
> my $m = ($a ~~ m:g/ (an)+ /)
(｢ananananananan｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣)
> say $m[0];
｢ananananananan｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
> say $m[0][1]
Nil
> say $m[0][0]
[｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣ ｢an｣]
> say $m[0][0][1]
｢an｣
> my $n = ($a ~~ m:g/ (an) /)
(｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣)
> say $n[0]
｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
> say $n[0][0]
｢an｣
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules which cause those different outputs are:

- `m/ /` matches the regex once, and returns a `Match` object if it succeeded, or `Nil` if it didn't.
- `m:g/ /` matches the regex repeatedly as often as it matches, and returns a `List` of zero or more `Match` objects.
- `( )` inside a regex causes one positional capture, which is itself a `Match` object.
- `( )*` inside a regex causes one positional capture, which is a `List` of zero or more `Match` objects.
- `( )+` inside a regex causes one positional capture, which is a `List` of one or more `Match` objects.
- Positional captures are available using `.[ ]` on the parent `Match` object, or as `$0`, `$1`, `$2`...

So in your example:

- `m/ (an)+ /` Returns the match `｢ananananananan｣`, which has one positional capture that is a list of seven `｢an｣` matches.

  ---
- `m:g/ an /` Returns a list of seven `｢an｣` matches without any captures.

  ---
- `m:g/ (an) /` Returns a list of seven `｢an｣` matches, each of which has one positional capture that is an `｢an｣` match.

I think your confusion may be caused by the way `say` prints summaries of lists and matches.
For the last example, in particular, `say` prints the result as:

```perl6
(｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣ ｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣)
```

...which is actually a list of seven `Match` objects, each of which is

```perl6
｢an｣
 0 => ｢an｣
```

Comment: Aha !!! Thank you smls !!! The fine flavors and nuances of the language takes time to savor and digest :-) Thank you !!!